# Есть ли способ прекратить работу функции

Tags: javascript, функции, map, leafletjs

При нажатии на кнопку у меня выходит окно слева от карты, включается возможность вставки маркера на экран, после закрытия окна возможность вставки маркера должна исчезнуть. Прикрутил его на чекбокс чтобы он работал только при его включение, а при включении отключался, но не получилось. Только начинаю работать с этим языком, и буду рад любой помощи. Спасибо.

```
document.querySelector('.checkbox').addEventListener('click',() =>{
  if(document.querySelector('.checkbox').checked){
      var theMarker = {};

      map.on('click', function (e) {
        lat = e.latlng.lat;
        lon = e.latlng.lng;

        console.log("You clicked the map at LAT: " + lat + " and LONG: " + lon);
        //Clear existing marker,

        if (theMarker != undefined) {
          map.removeLayer(theMarker);
        }
        ;

        //Add a marker to show where you clicked.
        theMarker = L.marker([lat, lon]).addTo(map);

      });
  }else {
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

*Есть ли способ прекратить работу функции*

---

Завершить функцию можно оператором  [return.](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Обратите внимания: Он не просто прекратит выполнение функции, но и вернет значение. Это означает, что вызов функции будет тем, что вы вернули, как результат.

Прекратить работу в цикле можно break;